# When should "that" be added?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, prepositions

Here are some examples to show what I mean:

> some sports that I like to practice are basketball, tennis...

or

> some sports I like to practice are basketball, tennis...

In what situation should I add "that" to sentences like these? Are both of these examples correct? What meaning does "that" have in this context?

Comment: Thanks for editing my post, I didn't know my english was this bad :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: I would leave "that" in.

Long answer: Leaving "that" in is more formal than taking it out.

According to this [blog](http://www.rebecaschiller.com/grammar/keep-that-or-drop-that/), which itself was a summary of two different grammar books on this subject, it's a question of formality (see 5 in the above link).

Meanwhile, both are correct and it's just a question of who your audience is and how you want to sound when speaking to them.

If you want to know which we would choose for your exact situation, I would suggest you let us know in which context your writing this. If it is an essay, as I am assuming it is, I would leave in "that".

Comment: It sounds incomplete to my ear when *that* is omitted. I think omitting *that* is just something that native speakers learn unconsciously

Comment: @user178049 You're probably right :D. Native speakers do often like to butcher their own languages.

Comment: There is no context behind these exemples, I asked this question because I could'nt figure the grammatical rule concerning the use of "that". Well, thanks for your answer !

Comment: @Donegan I understand. Good to know and good luck!

Comment: @Donegan There are many rules about omitting *that* like *reduced relative clause* and *nominal complement*. You should search that, but sometimes it depends on the idiomaticality of the sentence itself and I think only native speakers have this sense.